# C fscanf complex format

Tags: c, format, scanf, format-string

I am trying to read this text from a file in C. Assume this is the file Input.txt

```
This is a description which can be up to 1024 characters long
First
Second
Thrid   Option  This is a description for third
Fourth
```

I want to read the 4 words *First*, *Second*, *Third*, *Fourth*, the rest will be discarded. I have the solution for this problem but I do not understand why it works:

```
char string[1024];
char words[4][256]; 
FILE *in = fopen("Input.txt", "r");

// Catch first line
fgets(string, 1024, in);

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    fscanf(in, "%255s[^\n]\n", words[i]);
    fscanf(in, "%*[^\n]\n");
}
```

The input file is expected in a special format.

- The first line is a description which can be up to 1024 characters long.
- Lines 2 to 5 are always in this format: "*Word* *tab* *Option* *tab* *Description* ". Word is mandatory, Option and Description are optional (see Input.txt for example)

I would be very grateful for an explanation of the different components of the format string, how they work and why this whole solution works.

*(I also couldn't find any specific information about how fscanf's format works, would be happy if someone could give me a reference)*

Comment: `"%255s[^\n]\n"` looks for a `[` after the `"%255s"`.  Strange code.

Comment: The effect of the `fgets()` will surprise you when the first line is exactly its maximum of 1024-characters (or if it is longer).

Comment: @chux I thought `%255s[^\n]` reads all characters but not the `\n` because of the `^`

Comment: I am also open for a better solution (best with explanation)

Comment: No, @Codey.  `%255s` skips leading whitespace, then reads up to 255 non-whitespace characters into the provided array.  After that `[^\n]`, directs `scanf` to read and consume the literal characters `[` and `^`, an arbitrary run of whitespace, and the literal character `]`.  In general, the attempt to read that first `[` will cause a matching failure.  You might have meant `%255s%*[^\n]%*c`, which is better, but probably not as good as just using `fgets()` to read whole lines.

Comment: So what would be a working solution? I can't figure it out as I am not so experienced with fgets and scanf.

Comment: @Codey Instead of `%255s[^\n]` perhaps you want `%255[^\n]`?  This is inferior to `fgets()` when reading a blank line like `"\n"` as `fscanf(in, "%255[^\n]` reads nothing then, leaving the `;'\n` in `in` and the target array unchanged.  Avoid  `fscanf()`, `scanf()` and grief.  Use `fgets()` to read a _line_ of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"and why this whole solution works" IMO, in the general case, it does not.

The 2nd `'\n'` in the 2 `fscanf(in, ...` formats makes this a weak solution.  That `'\n'` will scan in any number of line-feeds as well as any white space.  Better to continue using `fgets(string, ...)` and then `sscanf(string, ...)`

`"%255s[^\n]\n"` looks for a `[` after the `"%255s"`.  Strange code. [@John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410441/c-fscanf-complex-format?noredirect=1#comment79779315_46410441)

---

Instead

```
char string[1024+1+1];  // increase for the \n and the \0
char words[4][256]; 
FILE *in = fopen("Input.txt", "r");

// Catch first line
// fgets(string, 1024, in);
fgets(string, sizeof string, in);

// "%255s" 
// scan over yet do not save leading white-space
// scan and save up to 255 non-white-space characters.
// Append a null character to form a string
for(int i = 0; i < 4 &&  fgets(string, sizeof string, in); i++ ){
    if (sscanf(string, "%255s", words[i]) != 1) {
      words[i][0] = '\0'; // If line was all white-sapce
    }
    puts(words[i]);
}
```

Comment: I just copied the code and tried it but it gives me some weird output: `�$���!-`

Comment: @Codey Code corrected to `if (sscanf(string, "%255s", words[i])...`

Comment: Perfect now it works! But I still don't really understand why. So fgets reads the whole line. Does sscanf read the line again and "filter" it?

Comment: @Codey Almost.  `fgets()` read the _line_ and saved the result as a _string_ in `string[]`.  `sscanf(string, "%255s", words[i]) ` then parses that _string_ (not the line of the file), saving the initial non-white-space characters into `words[i]` as another  _string_.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks for your explanation!